# jquery validation should allow alphabets

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-validate

Can anyone please tell me jquery validation, that should validate only alphabets, i.e)

```
abcde - valid
12344  - not valid
ancd12 - not valid
asng$e  - not valid etc
```

this code will not work for above conditions.

```
alphabet: function(value, element, param) {
    return this.optional(element) || value.match(/[a-z]/gi);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use validation plugin method written specifically for this purpose, found in the [validation plugin additional-methods.js](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/blob/master/additional-methods.js)

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("lettersonly", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^[a-z]+$/i.test(value);
}, "Letters only please");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
alphabet: function(value, element, param) {
    return /^[A-z]+$/.test(value);
}
```

Comment: Why not use `test` which returns `true|false`?

Comment: @elclanrs - I've totally forgotten about `.test`.

Comment: @elclanrs I have used .test() inside validation.js, nothing is working

Comment: @Derek yes, .test() worked but RegExp mentioned was wrong and i have posted answer for my criteria